# Selecting either in array or null in Hibernate query language

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I would like to select `User`s that has group that has name in a given array or has null group.
This is my attempted query:
`@Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE (u.group is null OR u.group.name IN :groups)")
Optional<Page<User>> findUsersByKeywordAndGroupIncludingNullGroup(Pageable pageable, @Param("groups") String... groups);` but when I run I have an error in SQL syntax.
Therefore, is there a correct way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's because if u will not pass anything in `groups`. SQL query generated will be `SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.group is null OR u.group.name IN ()` which is invalid.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to check if `groups` is null?

Answer (score 2):

Problem with your query is
If you will pass **(null or empty) groups**, then the resultant query will become

```
select * from users where users.group is null or users.group in ()
```

Thus results in `Syntax Error near '('`

You can do a hack using *sPEL*

```
@Query("SELECT U FROM User U " +
       "WHERE U.group IS NULL " +
       "OR (1=:#{ #groups == null || #groups.size() == 0 ? 1 : 0} OR U.group.name IN :#{#groups})")
List findUserWithoutGroupOrInGroup(@Param("groups") List<String> groups);
```

Here, I have used a proxy condition

```
1=:#{ #groups == null || #groups.size() == 0 ? 1 : 0}
```

Second part of this condition `returns 1` if the parameter **groups is null or empty**, results in condition 1=1 being TRUE and thereby skipping `U.group.name IN :#{#groups}`

**This approach is not a recommended one, and also not scalable.**

In my opinion, you should fetch the `Users without any Group` and `Users in given group` separately. You can even fire there queries in parallel and control not to fire `Users in given group` if groups is empty.